# How to disable "use prediction service to load pages more quickly" on chrome browser from arguments

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, browser

I use selenium and due to this feature I get timeouts at 15 seconds.

```
[SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 15.000
```

It works without issue if I disable this option "use prediction service to load pages more quickly" manually from chrome settings.

But is there a way to disable this form arguments?
What I have already used and didn't work:

```
--disable-background-networking,
--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages and
--dns-prefetch-disable
```

Any other arguments which will do the trick?

Comment: Which chrome and chromedriver version?